# Getting unique category/sub-category pair from a table

Tags: mysql, distinct

I'm trying to retrieve a unique set of category/sub-category relationships from a table and I want to make sure I'm doing it right so I am getting all the data.

For example I want the below..

```
Animals -> Dogs
Animals -> Cats
Animals -> Reptiles
Cars -> Ford
Cars -> Toyota
Cars -> BMW
```

I don't want any duplicate sub-categories listed, however duplicates are wanted if they are in another category, such as..

```
Animals -> Dogs
Animals -> Cats
Animals -> Reptiles
Animals -> *General*
Cars -> Ford
Cars -> Toyota
Cars -> BMW
Cars -> *General*
```

I have the below code, which *seems* to work well, but just wanted to check if it's the correct way of doing it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(category),subcategory FROM aall ORDER BY category ASC, subcategory ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will return a distinct list of `category, subcategory`  However, there's one important thing you need to know:

DISTINCT isn't a function! `DISTINCT(category)` isn't really doing a distinct on one column like it might appear from the syntax.  The correct way to write that is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category ,subcategory ...;
```

DISTINCT is a modifier that applies to *all* the columns you are selecting.  You can't say some should be distinct, but not others.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was how it worked, but when I added `sub_category` inside the parentheses I got a syntax error; guess I should just leave the parentheses off from now on then!? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `category`, `subcategory` 
FROM `aall` 
GROUP BY `category`, `subcategory` 
ORDER BY `category`, `subcategory`
```